# Export Application Settings to Shared Network Directory - Load / Import Settings on Startup

Tags: vb.net, settings

Can I export my application settings to a shared network drive and then 'point' users to it, essentially using this as a project settings 'ini' file.

I am referring to the system generated settings file created by the application. i.e. C:\APP_NAME\My Project\Settings.settings

For example I wish for all users on a particular project to use the same database connection string which is persisted in the application settings.

I would like the following functionality:

- Administrator exports their application settings.
- Users point to the exported settings file.
- Settings file is used at startup for all users.

I have written a class to export a .txt file and transpose the settings at startup, but surely importing and exporting the settings file itself is a much more efficient and less error prone solution.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done is correct. If you have written a method to read / import the settings at start, is this what you plan to achieve?

Couple of questions to go further into this...

1. What kind of settings are you actually trying to load? Are these startup dependent? or can they be loaded into the program at a later time? I.e. after the initial start / form has loaded?
2. Have you got access to SQL or MYSQL or similar? - If so you could write a small table with list of users or user groups and settings, then retrieve these using a hardcoded connection string (or another way you please), this can then be updated / modified by other 'Specified' users

It might even be nice to create a users table / csv to hold each user and then their permissions / group.

If you are not using SQL / MYSQL how are you making sure the text file cant be read, altered? Maybe look into some simple encryption (Its VERY easy, if this is needed at all?)

Comment: Hi Richard, I was hoping to remove my method to import / export settings and utilise the in-built 'My.Settings object' functionality.  My application settings are dynamically saved on close and read on startup.  I just want to export the user.config file and have others point this exported version, rather than their own local version.

Comment: Hi GoodJuJu, I used to use the My.Settings too, but the trouble is they run as soon as the App starts, which does get tricky when trying to load into before the begin. You could look at creating a separate app, almost like an updater - run this which copies the settings file accross, then use the Process.start method to run your app. I do this for one program, to check for update files etc and copy them over, so i know it works, but tbh i prefer loading settings once the app is opened my preference only though!

Comment: Sorry that was a bit vague - so user loads "App1" when double clicking shortcut, This opens "App1" which then checks for the settings file, and copies if needed. "App1" then uses System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MainApp.exe") method and opens "MainApp". "App1" then exits itself, and you have your settings and MainApp all correct :)